# Is there a "smarter" way to know the size of \psbarcode?

Tags: pstricks, preview, pst-barcode

The size of 2D barcode depends on the first argument of `\psbarcode`. I usually do trial and error to find the size of `\pspicture` such that I get a tight output.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=1bp
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}

\def\s{1.765}% I find this value by trial and error.

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(\s,\s)
    \psbarcode{http://example.org}{eclevel=L}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Is there a "smarter" way to know the size of `\psbarcode`?

Edit 1: Please make sure you don't remove the `preview` package and compile it with either `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` or `xelatex`.

Edit 2:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=1bp
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}

\usepackage{multido}

\begin{document}

\multido{\n=1.50+0.05}{15}{%
\begin{pspicture}(\n,\n)
        \psframe[linecolor=blue,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow](\n,\n)
    \psbarcode{http://example.org}{eclevel=L}{qrcode}
    \rput[tr](\n,\n){{\color{red}\n}}
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Changing `\s` does not have any effect on the output. Please give an example where it has some. Also, how do you create the pdf file?

Comment: I use exactly your source code. Or is there some more meaning to "using `preview`"? Ok your edit made it clear. compiling with `xelatex` did not work. But after applying `dvips` and `ps2pdf` the page got smaller.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pst-barcode}
\begin{document}

\fbox{\begin{pspicture}(2in,2in)
    \psbarcode{http://example.org}{eclevel=L width=2 height=2}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

Internally the width/height are used in inch, but you can set this one also on TeX side

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a specific size Hebert's answer is certainly correct. Otherwise you have to calculate, which version of the QR Code has to be used. That depends on the error correction level and the number of bytes you want to store. Assuming you are using level *n*, the QR Code has a side length of *4n+17* blocks. Each block has a side length of *0.07* which gives you for `\s` the formula ***1.2+0.28n***.

According to my tests you will get the following levels with `eclevel=L`:

> 0-17 chars – Level 1
>
> 18-32 chars – Level 2
>
> 33-53 chars – Level 3
>
> 54-78 chars – Level 4

This is useful for example if you have QR Codes of different sizes but want them to look homogeneous.

Comment: Nice idea, but unfortunately this isn't quite correct. The internal codeword length isn't a simple function of the input length except for a very constrained domain.

Comment: There are several different encoding modes which have different efficiencies for various types of data (alphanumeric, numeric-only, kanji and byte). pst-barcode switches between these modes in order to obtain an optimal encoding (minimum number of codewords), which results in the smallest symbol. The algorithm to achieve this is complex. See the following PostScript: https://github.com/bwipp/postscriptbarcode/blob/master/src/qrcode.ps#L327

Comment: If the worse case for the input data is known, a fixed sized output can be obtained using the *version* option, e.g. `\psbarcode{http://example.org}{eclevel=L version=10}{qrcode}`. Otherwise Herbert's solution with variable symbol density is as good as you can hope for (in the general case).